# Uncaught error with a function within a class

Tags: php, class

There must be some misunderstanding with my implementation of the function `$get_ship_class -> check_array($category,$cat_in_class = array());` because it's throwing the error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to
>   function get_ship_class::check_array(), 0 passed in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\php_sandbox\assign_ship_class.php on line 60 and at
>   least 1 expected in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\php_sandbox\assign_ship_class.php:45 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\php_sandbox\assign_ship_class.php(60):
>   get_ship_class->check_array() #1 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\php_sandbox\assign_ship_class.php on line 45

in response, I tried `$get_ship_class->check_array($category, $cat_in_class = array())` and it didn't work.

Essentially the first function `get_class_categories()` retrieves the product categories under a specific shipping class as an array.

`function get_product_category($category)` retrieves the category of the current product at hand - we will pretend; set $category = "Monitors" in this case.

Lastly `check_array();` just checks if $category = Monitors matches any elements in the list of categories for this shipping class, which was generated by the `get_class_categories()` function.

```
  <?php

class get_ship_class
{
    public function get_class_categories()
    {
        $csv = array_map("str_getcsv", file("Shipping Classes.csv"));
        /*
print_r($csv);
echo "<br />";
*/
                                        $header = array_shift($csv); 
// Separate the header from data

        /*
 print_r($header);
echo "<br />";
*/
                                        $col = array_search("Com1_34-95", $header);

        /*
print_r($col);
*/
        foreach ($csv as $row) {
            $array[] = $row[$col];
        }
        $cat_in_class = array_filter($array);
        print_r($cat_in_class);


    //https://stackoverflow.com/a/30909191/9095603
        $this->check_array($cat_in_class); // pass array onto function below
    }

    public function get_product_category()
    {
        $this->category = 'Monitor';    
//echo $this->category;
    }

    public function check_array($category, $cat_in_class = array())
    {

// https://stackoverflow.com/a/6431836/9095603
//$this->category='Monitor';
        $this->category;
        if (in_array($this->category, $cat_in_class)) {
            echo "Match detected!";
        }
    }
}

$get_ship_class = new get_ship_class();
$get_ship_class->get_product_category('Monitors');
//echo '<br />';
$get_ship_class->get_class_categories();
//echo '<br />';
$get_ship_class->check_array();
```

Comment: Do you understand the error text "Too few arguments to function get_ship_class::check_array()"?

Comment: Yes - I tried `$get_ship_class->check_array($category, $cat_in_class = array())` and it didn't work.

Comment: And where is `$category` defined?

Comment: I thought it was defined in `get_product_category()`, the function above in the same class?

Comment: Please look through your code and try to understand what's going on in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @u_mulder. Regardless, I'm trying to give you an answer.

Your code calls the `check_array` function twice:

1. At the end of the `get_class_categories` function, handing over exactly one argument: `$cat_in_class` - not TWO
2. At the end of your php file, handing over null arguments.

I suggest you to perform a code review. Once you have identified the control flow, you should be able to fix it. (Please let getXX functions return a value, if they don't name they setXX and let they write their results to object variables...)

Comment: Can you please explain point 2. about handing over null arguments at the end of the PHP file?  If it's the end of the PHP file, there's no more functions to follow so exactly what am I handing over arguments over to?  I apologise if the errors seem elementary but I'm a novice, and it's really difficult to know where I'm wrong unless people spell it out for me.

Comment: At the end of your PHP file means at line 58, the last line. There is a statement: `$get_ship_class->check_array();` which calls the `check_array()` function without any argument (or even null arguments).

Comment: OK, I'd like to give you some further advise.

At fist, you should complete some kind of php for beginners online course to ease the successful entry to the PHP programming language and concepts.

Secondly, I've revised your script, so that it fulfills the purpose I guessed. Please take a look at https://pastebin.com/vaL4nyT8

(From an object-oriented point of view the variables should be fields of the object, so no parameters have to be passed to the functions. But the returning and passing the values to the methods better illustrates the control flow)

Comment: @shau I've answered your question in deep. Please take a look at the comments in the revised code. So, why not marking as answer?

Comment: Sorry I've been slow to answer - apart from us being in a drastically different time zone, I think my limited understanding of PHP is bogging me down.  I need to do a quick crash course before I can follow.  I will revisit this when I have enough foundations to follow.  In the meantime, I'm giving you a provision accepted answer, as I anticipate your answer will be helpful.

Comment: @shau OK. Good luck. (See also here: [Teach Yourself Programming in Ten Years](http://norvig.com/21-days.html))